# How to use favicon by Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, favicon

I followed the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons) but the favicon did not appear. How can I fix it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

and here is my source

```
//layout.tsx

import './styles'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'profile-card',
  description: '프로필 카드 페이지',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="ko">
      <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

I tried the Next.js document.

Comment: Out of the docs I can see you don't have to add the `<head>` to your code. NextJS will do that for you: `Next.js will evaluate the file and automatically add the appropriate tags to your app's <head> element.`
Try omitting the `<head>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to add that `head` or the `link` yourself. You just need the file in the right directory with the right name as shown on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons):

[image]

If you are still not seeing it, try hard refreshing the browser, stopping your development server, and starting again.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to do anything, just replace the favicon.ico inside the public folder with your original favicon.ico file. NextJS will automatically render it on the client page.
For example:
[You can view the picture below.] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr5n4.png)

No need to stress about favicon.ico file in NextJS 13.0

Answer (score 0):

Create a `public` folder in the root of your project next to the app folder and put the favicon.ico in there.

Now the favicon.ico should be available via `http://localhost:3001/public/favicon.ico`

Afterwards add the following `rewrite` to the next.config.js in your project root:

```
module.exports = {
// ...
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*/favicon.ico',
        destination: '/favicon.ico',
      },
    ]
  },
// ...
}
```

This causes the favicon no matter where it is to be available over `http://localhost:3001/favicon.ico`

With this your website should be able to detect the icon.

Answer (score 0):

That my way how I do this in next: 14.0.2

```
import { Metadata } from "next";

import DarkIcon from "@/images/dark/logo-dark.png";
import LightIcon from "@/images/light/logo-light.png";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Your Title",
  icons: {
    icon: [
      {
        rel: "icon",
        media: "(prefers-color-scheme: light)",
        type: "image/png",
        url: LightIcon.src,
      },
      {
        rel: "icon",
        media: "(prefers-color-scheme: dark)",
        type: "image/png",
        url: DarkIcon.src,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

NextJs Optimizing Static Assets url to files in public folder, and for that I take current src on files that I need